# Campo de Pesquisa de Telas (ASP.Net - MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, aplicação-web

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar. Sou iniciante na programação, e estou desenvolvendo um sistema Web, e preciso de uma tela de pesquisa das telas que já tem criadas.

Como uso o método MVC, queria saber se tenho que criar uma View/Controller com o nome Pesquisa.

**Lembrando que quero deixar isso na tela inicial, e quando pesquisar, queria que explodisse uma caixa com os resultados, similar ao processo que o site (https://trello.com) realiza.

Agradeço por ter lido até aqui!

Uso o VS2013,e o banco usamos o SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

O que fiz em um sistema meu foi criar um `Controller` comum que implementa o método de pesquisa. Algo assim:

```
public abstract class Controller<TSource> : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    where TSource: class, IPesquisavel, new()
{
    protected MeuContext db = new MeuContext();

    public ActionResult Pesquisar(String termo)
    {
        var lista = db.Set<TSource>().Where(s => s.TermoPesquisa.Contains(termo)).ToList();
        return View(lista);
    }
}
```

A *View* você pode colocar em `Views/Shared` (um pouco mais complexa de implementar), ou então fazer uma *View* `Pesquisar.cshtml` para cada *Controller* que tenha essa pesquisa.

Implemente `IPesquisavel` assim:

```
public interface IPesquisavel
{
    String TermoPesquisa { get; }
}
```

O *Model* que pode receber esta pesquisa fica assim:

```
public class MeuModel 
{
    ...
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Descricao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Termo de Pesquisa")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public String TermoPesquisa
    {
        // No get, coloque os campos que interessam pra pesquisa, separados
        // por vírgula. Por exemplo, Nome e Descricao
        get { return Nome + ", " + Descricao; }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

Ao gerar a *Migration*, o Entity Framework não entende que é um campo calculado. Comente a geração dele e escreva na mão:

```
public partial class TestePesquisavel : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        // AddColumn("dbo.MeuModels", "TermoPesquisa", c => c.String());
        Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.MeuModels ADD TermoPesquisa AS Nome + ', ' + Descricao");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // DropColumn("dbo.MeuModels", "TermoPesquisa");
        Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.MeuModels drop column TermoPesquisa");
    }
}
```

Comment: no meu caso, tenho uma View já no `Shared` chamado **_Layout**, onde aqui tem o menu do sistema, e a pesquisa queria colocá-la aqui também. No caso, um Controller já resolveria?

Comment: Dá pra fazer. Vai ficar um pouco mais complicado porque você vai ter que usar `Reflection` pra ler as propriedades e escrever direitinho, mas funciona.

Comment: Sugere algum outro método para alguém leigo e pouca experiência?

Comment: Este é o método mais simples que conheço, que é o de justamente implementar uma *Action* comum a todos os *Controllers*. Os demais partem de excentricidades desnecessárias.

Comment: Bom dia @Cigano, poderia me tirar mais uma dúvida por favor? Estou adaptando o código para meu sistema, o que seria o "MeuContext"?

Comment: @MarioPueblaJunior Seria seu contexto de dados. Estou supondo que você está usando o Entity Framework.